# Totally right preorderable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, order-theory, ordered-groups

Are there any known non-trivial sufficient conditions, or full characterizations, of a totally right-preorderable group?

More precisely:

- **totally right-preorderable**: has a non-trivial total right-preorder
- **non-trivial total right-preorder**: transitive and symmetric relation ("preorder") $\le$ with $a\le b$ or $b\le a$ for all $a,b$ ("total"), with $a\le b$ iff $ac\le bc$ ("right"), and with $a\not\le b$ for some $a,b$ ("non-trivial")

I couldn't find anything in the literature on total right preorderability (but perhaps I didn't know the terminology to look under).

Obvious facts about total right-preorderability:

- having a right-orderable quotient is sufficient
- in particular, indicability (non-trivial homomorphism to $\mathbb Z$) is sufficient
- not being generated by elements of finite order is necessary
- equivalent to total left-preorderability (but perhaps with a different preorder--same proof as for the equivalence of right- and left-orderability)

A more specific question then is whether the first or the third fact has a true converse?  (The second doesn't, since there are right-orderable groups that have a non-indicable subgroup.)  Or at least a converse given some nice assumptions?

A related question: Are there non-trivial sufficient conditions for having a right-orderable quotient?

Comment: What you call "complete" pre-orders are also commonly called *linear* pre-orders, and also sometimes they are called *total* pre-orders.

Comment: to admit a *faithful* order-preserving action on a totally ordered set and to be left-orderable are equivalent. So it follows from my answer that your condition (being totally left-preorderable) is indeed equivalent to the existence of a nontrivial left-orderable quotient.

Comment: a torsion-free finite index subgroup in $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is not left-orderable (I guess this is due to Witte), and all its proper quotients are finite (Bass-Milnor-Serre), hence is not totally left-preorderable. This shows that the converse of your third fact is far from true.

Comment: I don't know why I used "complete" instead of "total" in the question.  I think it's because one of the last things I had read on preorders used "complete".  I think "total" or "linear" is indeed more standard, so I changed it to "total".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A group $G$ admits a nontrivial preorder iff it admits a nontrivial order-preserving action on a totally ordered set (which can be chosen to be $\mathbf{Q}$ or its completion $\mathbf{R}$ if $G$ is countable).

Proof:
[I like left actions rather than right actions so I'll go ahead with left-invariant instead of right-invariant: you can pass from one to another by inversion.]

Indeed suppose that $G$ admits such an action. Let $x$ be not fixed by all of $G$. Define $g\le h$ if $gx\le hx$. Then this is a non-trivial left-invariant total preorder on $G$.

Conversely, suppose that $G$ has a left-invariant total preorder $\le$. Let $H$ be the set of elements  $h$ such that $1\le h\le 1$. Then $H$ is a subgroup: left-multiplying the latter by $h^{-1}$ shows it's stable by inversion, and if $1\le g\le 1$ as well, multiplying the former on the left by $g$ yields $g\le gh\le g$, whence $1\le gh\le 1$.

The preorder is actually right-$H^2$-invariant, in the sense that $g\le g'$ and $h,h'\in H$ implies $gh\le g'h'$. Indeed, we have $gh\le g\le g'\le g'h'$. 
The coset space $G/H$ inherits a $G$-invariant total order by $gH\le g'H$ iff $g\le g'$, this does not depend on the choices of $g,g'$ because of the above right $H^2$-invariance.

If moreover $G/H$ is countable, you can just take the lexicographic product $(G/H)\times\mathbf{Q}$ (with trivial action on $\mathbf{Q}$) to get an action on $\mathbf{Q}$. Taking completion also yields an action on $\mathbf{R}$.

---

In some cases you have an even simpler characterization. Indeed, a theorem of Witte (*Alg. Geom. Topol.* 2006, [arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606232); [ProjectEuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513796645)) can be restated as: a *finitely generated amenable* group $G$ admits a nontrivial order-preserving action on some totally ordered set (or on the real line, it's the same) if and only if it admits $\mathbf{Z}$ as a quotient.

---

Edit: Here's a direct proof (not using actions) that if $G$ admits a nontrivial left-invariant total preorder $\le$, then it admits a nontrivial left-orderable quotient: fix a strict well-ordering $\prec$ on the set $G$ (unrelated to the group structure and $\le$: if $G$ is countable just take an enumeration of $G$), and say that $g\not\le' g'$ if there exists $h\in G$ such that $gh\not\le g'h$ and $gh'\le g'h'\le gh'$ for every $h'\prec h$. Then $\le'$ is another left-invariant total preorder, but has the additional feature that the set $N$ of $g$ such that $1\le' g\le' 1$ is a normal subgroup ($N$ is indeed, using that $\prec$ is a well-ordering, the set of $g$ such that $1\le h^{-1}gh\le 1$ for all $h\in G$). Moreover $N$ is contained in the subgroup $\{g:1\le g\le 1\}$ and hence is not all of $G$. So the quotient $G/N$ is a nontrivial left-orderable group.

Comment: Your answer here helped me to get a pretty much complete answer to another question of mine: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146440/two-kinds-of-invariance-of-full-conditional-probabilities/146917#146917 .  So thank you again!

Comment: I am having some trouble following your last direct proof.  By your definition, we have $g\le' g'$ iff for all $h\in H$ we have $gh\le g'h$ or there is an $h'\prec h$ such that not: $gh'\le g'h'\le gh'$.  But as you showed, $\le$ is right $H$-invariant, so the first disjunct is just equivalent to $g\le g'$.  Thus $\le'$ is weaker than $\le$ and so $\{ g : 1 \le g \le 1 \}\subseteq N$.  But you claim the opposite inclusion (and surely in general they aren't equal).  What am I missing?

Comment: $\le'$ is stronger than $\le$, in the sense that the relation $\le'$ is contained in the relation $\le$.

Comment: Let's restate the definition: say that $g\equiv g'$ if $g\le g'\le g$, and $g\equiv\!\!\!\!\!/\;g'$ otherwise. If $g\neq g'$, then there exists $h$ such that $gh\equiv\!\!\!\!\!/\;g'h$; we pick such $h$ minimal for $\prec$ and define $g\le'g'$ or $g\ge'g'$ according to whether $gh\le gh'$ or $gh\ge gh'$.

Comment: But since $\le$ is right $H$-invariant, if $g\ne g'$ and $h\in H$, then $gh \equiv g'h$ iff $g \equiv g'$.  Thus the minimal $h$ will always be the same (i.e., the $\prec$-minimal member of $H$).  Perhaps you have a typo, though, and meant $h\in G$ instead of $h\in H$?  I was assuming $H=\{ g : 1 \le g \le 1 \}$, as earlier in your post.

Comment: @Alexander: in my post I wrote "if $G$ admits a nontrivial *left*-invariant total preorder..."

Comment: OK, I see it now.  You must have had "$h\in G$" instead of "$h\in H$".  I know that you're talking of a left-invariant total preorder, but nonetheless as you correctly said "The preorder is actually right-$H$-invariant" (but not necessarily right $G$-invariant).